# Bootstrap Typeahead Escaping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

So I'm using the Bootstrap typeahead plugin to display a list of classes. It works fine for most courses, but if you click the dropdown for Driver's Education, the text displays in the input field as "Driver&#39;s Education".

Is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you define your source array as a data attribute, and therefore is interpreted with HTML-entities. To the opposit, when the options is defined in a javascript handler special chars as `'` will show up normal when the list dropdowns and afterwards in the input field when you have clicked :

HTML wthout data attributes :

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" id="stackoverflow">
```

jquery constructer instead :

```
$("#stackoverflow").typeahead({
   "source" : ["Driver's Education", "Toys'r'us Education"] //and so on
   //(,) rest of options, if any
});
```